# How can I filter data only by date without comparing their times in bit framework?

Tags: javascript, bit-framework

I've following codes:

```
// 2017-Sep(09)-05 is selected in date picker

const dateToSearch = new Date(2017, 8 /*Month starts from zero*/, 5);

// context is oData context.

const customersOfThatSpecificDay = await context.customers.filter((c, d) => c.BirthDate == day, { day: dateToSearch }).toArray();
```

But it returns no data as it's comparing both date & time values for each customer. How can I compare them only by date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that customer's BirthDate is saved in a column with DateTimeOffset type.

**Even when there is no need to "time" in your scenario and you need "date" only, you've to use DateTimeOffset, because of time zones side effects.**

```
// 2017-Sep(09)-05 is selected in date picker

const dateToSearch = new Date(2017, 8 /*Month starts from zero*/, 5, new Date().getHours(), new Date().getMinutes(), new Date().getSeconds()).toISOString();

// dateToSearch variable which is produced from your date picker must have two important things: 1- It should be in ISO format. 2- It's hour/minute/second should be the client's current date/time's hour/minute/second.

const customersOfThatSpecificDay = await context.customers.filter((c, d) => c.BirthDate.date() == d, { d: `date"${dateToSearch}"` }).toArray();

// This results into following odata query: (date(BirthDate) eq 'date"2017-09-05T08:06:05.000Z"')
```

**c.BirthDate.date()** means BirthDate without Time, even when it's saved in a column with DateTimeOffset type.

Notice that you've to submit current system time in your query (08:06:05.000Z in this sample) to server, and at server side, we determinate **correct date** based on time zone offset calculations. **Without this, your solution is somehow incomplete**, specially for globally distributed applications which have customers all across the world.

When we converted 'date"2017-09-05T08:06:05.000Z"' to something like 2017-09-05 without time, we're ready to compare two **valid** times.